# Percentage of process

Tags: php, jquery, post

I do a post with jQuery to a PHP script that do some tasks.

```
$.post("script.php", params, function(data) { // task done }
```

In script.php I know in each moment how much percentage of the complete task have been done. At the end, PHP writes a `json_encode()` string with the data that the first HTML receives and then completes the `$.post` call.

What I'd like is to tell (for example, each second) from script.php to the HTML the percentage of the tasks done (to print that in screen)

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 2):

You can store the status of your php script server side with memcached or even a single text file.

Create a php that reads out this status, and return its value.

Now start your script, and also start the status checking, which you can run every 1000 ms.

Answer (score 0):

It's technically possible, with a keep-alive connection, but it's complicated to implement.